# Google Adwords API (2018) to Google Ads API in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I am looking for the equivalents of Adwords API in the new Google ads API in PHP.

For example, the equivalent of

```
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\AgeRange;
```

is

```
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V10\Common\AgeRangeInfo;
```

**But I can't find the exact equivalents for those for example:**

```
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\GeoTargetTypeSetting;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\GeoTargetTypeSettingNegativeGeoTargetType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\GeoTargetTypeSettingPositiveGeoTargetType;
```

*Do you know any translators from google adwords to google ads?*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's complete "translators" as such. You can find a mapping of Adwords API reports to Ads API resources [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/migration/mapping) and general concepts and pointers for the migration [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/migration).

As for your specific example, the corresponding type in the Ads API is also called [`GeoTargetTypeSetting`](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v10/Campaign.GeoTargetTypeSetting).